# symfony2 valid w3.org xhtml - sf2 form validation fails the w3.org validator

Tags: forms, html, validation, xhtml, symfony

I've got a problem with valid w3.org XHTML - the validator shows an error on the `required` attribute of an input:

`There is no attribute "required".`

I believe that this attribute is essential and it is added by symfony2 form builder to validate the form. What can I do about that?

```
<input type="text" id="form_dateStartEnergy" name="form_dateStartEnergy" required="required" value="2012-05-29" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `required` attribute is define is the [HTML5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-required-attribute).

Check that your Doctype is OK with that.

Comment: I am using the Doctype for HTML 4. I guess I have to make the decision which one to use..